# Get topic from kafka message

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, apache-kafka

How can I identify the topic name from a message in **kafka**.

```
String[] topics = { "test", "test1", "test2" };
    for (String t : topics) {
        topicMap.put(t, new Integer(3));
    }

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
            .set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "false")
            .setMaster("local[4]")
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost");
    ;
    final JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(
            1000));

    /* Receive Kafka streaming inputs */
    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils
            .createStream(jssc, "localhost:2181", "test-group",
                    topicMap);

   JavaDStream<MessageAndMetadata> data = 
          messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, MessageAndMetadata>() 
          {

              public MessageAndMetadata call(Tuple2<String, String> message)
              {
                  System.out.println("message ="+message._2);
                  return null;
              }
          }

          );
```

I can fetch message from kafka producer. But since the consumer now consuming from three topic, it is needed to identify topic name.

Comment: I'm very interested in the answer to this. Did you find a way?

Comment: @Arun: Did you find a solution? If so, could you share it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of Spark 1.5.0, [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html) encourages using no-receiver/direct approach starting from recent releases, which has graduated from experimental in recent 1.5.0.
This new Direct API allows you to easily obtain message and its metadata apart from other good things.

Comment: I am using the direct approach and do not understand how to get message metadata. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @BrandonBradley, Please see last code snippet in official documentation following the link above. Basically, you have to cast RDD to HasOffsetRanges as soon as you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not straightforward as KafkaReceiver and ReliableKafkaReceiver in Spark's source code only store MessageAndMetadata.key and message.

There are two open tickets related to this issue in Spark's JIRA:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3146
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4960

which have been opened for a while.

A dirty copy/paste/modify of Spark's source code to solve your issue:

```
package org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka

import java.lang.{Integer => JInt}
import java.util.{Map => JMap, Properties}

import kafka.consumer.{KafkaStream, Consumer, ConsumerConfig, ConsumerConnector}
import kafka.serializer.{Decoder, StringDecoder}
import kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties
import org.apache.spark.Logging
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.{JavaReceiverInputDStream, JavaStreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver
import org.apache.spark.streaming.util.WriteAheadLogUtils
import org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.Map
import scala.reflect._

object MoreKafkaUtils {

  def createStream(
    jssc: JavaStreamingContext,
    zkQuorum: String,
    groupId: String,
    topics: JMap[String, JInt],
    storageLevel: StorageLevel = StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2
  ): JavaReceiverInputDStream[(String, String, String)] = {
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
      "zookeeper.connect" -> zkQuorum, "group.id" -> groupId,
      "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "10000")
    val walEnabled = WriteAheadLogUtils.enableReceiverLog(jssc.ssc.conf)
    new KafkaInputDStreamWithTopic[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](jssc.ssc, kafkaParams, topics.asScala.mapValues(_.intValue()), walEnabled, storageLevel)
  }

}

private[streaming]
class KafkaInputDStreamWithTopic[
  K: ClassTag,
  V: ClassTag,
  U <: Decoder[_] : ClassTag,
  T <: Decoder[_] : ClassTag](
    @transient ssc_ : StreamingContext,
    kafkaParams: Map[String, String],
    topics: Map[String, Int],
    useReliableReceiver: Boolean,
    storageLevel: StorageLevel
  ) extends ReceiverInputDStream[(K, V, String)](ssc_) with Logging {

  def getReceiver(): Receiver[(K, V, String)] = {
    if (!useReliableReceiver) {
      new KafkaReceiverWithTopic[K, V, U, T](kafkaParams, topics, storageLevel)
    } else {
      new ReliableKafkaReceiverWithTopic[K, V, U, T](kafkaParams, topics, storageLevel)
    }
  }
}

private[streaming]
class KafkaReceiverWithTopic[
  K: ClassTag,
  V: ClassTag,
  U <: Decoder[_] : ClassTag,
  T <: Decoder[_] : ClassTag](
    kafkaParams: Map[String, String],
    topics: Map[String, Int],
    storageLevel: StorageLevel
  ) extends Receiver[(K, V, String)](storageLevel) with Logging {

  // Connection to Kafka
  var consumerConnector: ConsumerConnector = null

  def onStop() {
    if (consumerConnector != null) {
      consumerConnector.shutdown()
      consumerConnector = null
    }
  }

  def onStart() {

    logInfo("Starting Kafka Consumer Stream with group: " + kafkaParams("group.id"))

    // Kafka connection properties
    val props = new Properties()
    kafkaParams.foreach(param => props.put(param._1, param._2))

    val zkConnect = kafkaParams("zookeeper.connect")
    // Create the connection to the cluster
    logInfo("Connecting to Zookeeper: " + zkConnect)
    val consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig(props)
    consumerConnector = Consumer.create(consumerConfig)
    logInfo("Connected to " + zkConnect)

    val keyDecoder = classTag[U].runtimeClass.getConstructor(classOf[VerifiableProperties])
      .newInstance(consumerConfig.props)
      .asInstanceOf[Decoder[K]]
    val valueDecoder = classTag[T].runtimeClass.getConstructor(classOf[VerifiableProperties])
      .newInstance(consumerConfig.props)
      .asInstanceOf[Decoder[V]]

    // Create threads for each topic/message Stream we are listening
    val topicMessageStreams = consumerConnector.createMessageStreams(
      topics, keyDecoder, valueDecoder)

    val executorPool =
      ThreadUtils.newDaemonFixedThreadPool(topics.values.sum, "KafkaMessageHandler")
    try {
      // Start the messages handler for each partition
      topicMessageStreams.values.foreach { streams =>
        streams.foreach { stream => executorPool.submit(new MessageHandler(stream)) }
      }
    } finally {
      executorPool.shutdown() // Just causes threads to terminate after work is done
    }
  }

  // Handles Kafka messages
  private class MessageHandler(stream: KafkaStream[K, V])
    extends Runnable {
    def run() {
      logInfo("Starting MessageHandler.")
      try {
        val streamIterator = stream.iterator()
        while (streamIterator.hasNext()) {
          val msgAndMetadata = streamIterator.next()
          store((msgAndMetadata.key, msgAndMetadata.message, msgAndMetadata.topic))
        }
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable => reportError("Error handling message; exiting", e)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You can also try to use the Experimental KafkaUtils.createDirectStream which takes a messageHandler: JFunction[MessageAndMetadata[K, V], R] as a parameter.